# Remove Lines with Out-of-order Duplicated Values

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file containing pairwise combinations for the numbers 1, 2, and 3.

Example input:

```
2 1
3 1
1 2
3 2
1 3
2 3
```

What I would like to do is remove one of the lines that have duplicated values, but that are not in order.

Example output:

```
2 1
3 1
3 2
```

For example: 2 1 is equivalent to 1 2, so remove one of these lines.

I will note that I have provided a small example, as I could also just pair these numbers pretty easily. I am looking to scale this to a file that has pairwise combinations for 4+ numbers. I am not sure how to proceed, and all internet searchers produce duplicated lines or duplicated columns. Please let me know how to improve this question/title. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Alternatively, I could always generate unique pairwise combinations of numbers. However, I suffer from the same issue of not finding an example similar to mine.

Comment: I fail to understand what is it that you want to do. Remove lines that should sort before the present line? Remove repeated lines?. Please clarify. Your example doesn't show what rule to apply to remove any line.

Comment: I added a sentence, hopefully it clarifies what I was looking for @Isaac.

Comment: I believe that the sentence was really needed as you've got two good answers just after adding it. Have you found what you were looking for?

Comment: @Isaac Sure did. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way involves keeping track of "seen" number pairs using an array

```
awk '!a[$1 < $2? $1 FS $2: $2 FS $1]++' file
2 1
3 1
3 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve what I wanted was to sort the numbers on the line and then remove the duplicates (as suggested in the comments by @alecxs). The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552930/sort-numbers-on-same-line-remove-duplicates-but-keep-original) is:

```
awk '$1>$2{$0=$2 OFS $1} 1' example.txt | sort -u
```

Where:

`$1>$2{$0=$2 OFS $1} sorts each line. sort -u removes duplicate lines.`

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
~$ cat 1.txt                                                                                                                                                                                   
2 1
3 1
1 2
3 2
1 3
2 3
~$ cat 1.txt| sort -nk1                                                                                                                                                                        
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 3
3 1
3 2
```

in `sort -nk1`

"n" - for numeric sort

"k1" - for sorting by first column

Comment: This just sorts the list, while useful to know is not what I am looking for.

Comment: i assume *cat* is only for demonstration, because *sort* can read files too. pipe the sorted output through *uniq* (or add the *sort -u* flag if available) and you have a valid answer

Comment: Using: cat 1.txt | sort -u -nk1, did not work. Using: cat 1.txt sort -nk1 | sort -u, did not work. Using cat: 1.txt | sort -nk1 | uniq, did not work. Did not work, as in not the desired result.

Comment: @alecxs yes, cat was only for demo. But from beginning I didn't understand task. For now I realized, that we, need script, that would be, for example adding each of column from one line in array. And then we can compare if [(number1 in array1) and (number2 in array2)] or [(number2 in array1) and (number1 in array2)] then we skipping line. In other case we, for example add it into another file

Comment: What I want to do is remove one pair of non-unique combinations from a file. Non-unique as in pair 1 2 is equal to pair 2 1. This is why there are only three lines in the example output, but six in the example input.

Comment: if 1 2 is equal 2 1 to you, then you must first sort words per line, then sort lines, then uniq

Comment: I am currently looking into that, it is what I figured would be needed. Thanks.